# GKE list namespaces of another cluster

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

I need a list of all namespaces inside all the clusters in a GKE Project.

`kubectl get ns` will return namespaces in current-content and it's not ideal to keep switching contexts to get namespaces. Is there something in gcloud cli which I can use?

`gcloud container clusters describe` doesn't show namespaces :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question.

Because there are 2-level of API interaction (Google Cloud, Kubernetes) and because each CLI (`gcloud`, `kubectl`) is configured distinctly, I think (!?) the only way to do this is by going through a `KUBECONFIG` configured with each cluster.

Repeatedly `gcloud container cluster get-credentials` is more expensive but should not be necessary. But context switching through `KUBECONFIG` is cheap and this should only entail updating the `current-context` value.

```bash
PROJECT="..."
```

Then to build the `KUBECONFIG`:

```bash
# Build KUBECONFIG comprising Project's clusters
# KUBECONFIG may include deleted Clusters
# Assumes that all the clusters are either REGION or ZONE
gcloud container clusters list \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--format="value(name,location)" |\
while read NAME LOCATION
do
  gcloud container clusters get-credentials ${NAME} \
  --region=${LOCATION} \
  --project=${PROJECT}
done
```

Then to iterate over it:

```bash
# Use the current Clusters in the Project as the source
# You could iterate over KUBECONFIG Clusters but this may not be current
gcloud container clusters list \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--format="value(name,location)" |\
while read NAME LOCATION
do
  kubectl config use-context gke_${PROJECT}_${LOCATION}_${NAME}
  kubectl get namespaces
done
```

Thinking about this again, there's an easier way. You don't need to revise the current context with `--use-context`, you can simply set the context on the `kubectl get namespaces` command:

```bash
gcloud container clusters list \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--format="value(name,location)" |\
while read NAME LOCATION
do
  kubectl get namespaces \
  --context=gke_${PROJECT}_${LOCATION}_${NAME}
done
```

###### Update

If your script has issues with `| while read NAME LOCATION`, please try the following alternative e.g. for the last example:

````bash
ROWS=$(\
  gcloud container clusters list \
  --project=${PROJECT} \
  --format="csv[no-heading](name,location)")

for ROW in ${ROWS}
do
  IFS=, read NAME LOCATION <<< ${ROW}
  kubectl get namespaces \
  --context=gke_${PROJECT}_${LOCATION}_${NAME}
done
```
````

Comment: I'm trying to add this to an array but it seems while loop is not happy being piped. Facing this issue - http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024.

Comment: IIUC, please try the alternative loop I've added to the answer